# How to listen socket.io message without using event Listener in postman

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

When using postman event listener, I'm getting messages but problem is that,

i don't want to listen to any event, then how can i get messages from the server

I want to get all messages when the server triggers client.send(data).

Is there any way to do this

Thanks.